# Android Constants

Tags: java, android, constants

I am working on some old code that we pulled from a decompiled APK (no one has the code base anymore, just the APK from our developer account).

There is a line of code in it:

```
localAlarmManager.setRepeating(3, 10000L + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 25200000L, localPendingIntent);
```

What are the Android constants that would be used in Android Studio for `10000L` and `25200000L`? I assume those are time intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up the docs for [`AlarmManager#setRepeating(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), you find that its signature is:

```
setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtMillis,
     long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)
```

So the long values are times.  This alarm triggers after 10 seconds, and every 7 hours thereafter.  As for the 3, you can find out which constant that corresponds to from the same docs.  The only mystery is why the original author used those particular intervals.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're asking what types 10000L and 23200000L are. They are `long` types. You can check out the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).